# Can i create a release pipeline that uses custom templates that are saved on a branch?

Tags: azure-devops, pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I was wondering if its possible to use custom templates for release pipelines if the templates are located on a different branch, because in Azure I don't see a button where I can choose a branch for a release pipeline.

Comment: Do you mean a .yml template? Typically you do not choose a branch on your release pipeline, source control download and building happens on build step.

Comment: Yes i meant a .yml template. Oh ok i see